# Python: Parallelizing GPU and CPU work

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, tensorflow

Processing batches for my ML models takes too much time so I am considering parallelizing them.

Right now preprocessing routine grabs data from SSD, does preprocessing and form a data structure for learning. All this time ML training process waits. Then ML process takes this data and uses it to train the model. Now preprocessing waits. And then they go round. This waiting time sums up quickly and delays model training.

The plan is the following: a single data structure would store a bunch of data points. Each step the training algorithm would take random subset of them to train the model (SGD with TensorFlow on GPU).

In parallel with that I would like another thread to do preprocessing of the next bunch of data points. And when preprocessing is ready it would replace old data structure object with the new one. And so forth.

As this is my first approach to parallelization in Python I wonder if this would work at all. Would global interpreter lock prevent the system from doing these tasks in a truly parallel way?

Comment: Have you found a way of doing this in Python, Keras/Tensorflow? Can this be done with the Multiprocessing library?

Comment: Since then, I have moved to PyTorch and found it much more convenient. They say, new versions of TF and Keras are good as well but I have not worked with them for about three years already.

Comment: So the solution you found was not using the Multiprocessing library from Python, but rather something intrinsic to PyTorch?

Comment: Yes, PyTorch provides Dataset class which, being combined with DataLoader class, does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow's Python binding is very diligent about releasing the global interpreter lock as soon as possible. For instance, it does not hold the lock when the control has transferred to the C++ library in the `tf.Session`'s `run` method. What you describe is a very common pattern in TensorFlow. Input data preprocessing and training an ML model using the preprocessed data are decoupled in TensorFlow using [queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#queues). There is an illustrative example of how input preprocessing and training are parallelized in the Inception [model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py).

Comment: For multi-threading, do you think TensorFlow can make `threading` real parallelism regardless of GIL in Python? Or when Python run TF code,  does TF can make it parallel?